# How to Schedule Tasks according to several Timezones

Tags: windows-7, cron, scheduled-tasks, time-zone

I need to use Windows Scheduler or any other app for setting jobs at a concrete time depending on destination country.

That means scheduling a job at 7 am (UK Timezone), another at 7 am (US Timezone), and so on. I would not like to mess with Daylight savings.

Do you know any way to do it in Windows native scheduling?

I also searched for any other GUI application, I'm surprised I could not find anything else with that feature...

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just set the system time zone to `Coordinated Universal Time` (i.e. UTC) and run the tasks that way. This way you don't have to worry about time zones nor daylight savings.

Comment: Because I don't need an absolute time accross timezones, but a way to specify a current time for any timezone (always 7:00 am UK, always 9:00 US, no matter what daylight saving compensation has been done, I want current 9:00 for THAT country)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why is UK 7AM and US 9AM? Why not run them the sametime hence the reason UTC could be used.

Comment: Sorry it is because my english. Because 7 UK or 9 US or 12 Botswana constantly changes. So it is not that I need to specify an absolute time (UTC) but a time updated according a TimeZone (daylight saving, different changing flag days and so)

Comment: 8AM UTC will equal the same relative time in US, UK timezones though out the year. I disagree that 9 EST changes its still 9AM its just offset by an hour half the time but its still 9AM EST.

Comment: Mmmh... Does UTC equals to an absolute specific moment of time no matter how we call it in each country as I always assumed or is it just a way to say 'each country's 9 o'clock' whether it's june, august, beijing or botswana

Comment: To put it another way, do you mean that you want (for example) an Australian task to run 10 hours after a UK task, but when UK has daylight savings, you want it to run only 9 hours after the UK task? So the time difference between different tasks dynamically change when daylight savings change in different countries?

Comment: Yes. I want 10 am Aus always no matter what is the difference compared to UK in relative time. It's like having a cron and asking everyday is it today 10 am in australia? Yes, they changed the time for daylight. Ok, compensate and keep executing at 10 am for australia.